# map() in React with a find condition

Tags: reactjs, dictionary

I have the following code,
where ItemNamesAndIds is an array of names and ids
If the id does not exist inside the schemes the system is crashing with an error
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Name' of undefined

```
const items = x.ItemNamesAndIds
          .map((id) => schemes.find((x) => x.id === id).Name)
          .reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}, ${cur}`);
```

How can I add a condition in the same line to say something like if Name === "undefined" then Name = "empty"
Sorry I am new to react

Answer (score 1):

```
const items = x.ItemNamesAndIds
      .map((id) => {
        const matchedSchemes = schemes.find((x) => x.id === id);

        if (matchedSchemes.length !== 0) {
            return matchedSchemes.Name;
        } else {
            return 'undefined';
        }
      })
      .reduce((acc, cur) => `${acc}, ${cur}`);
```

Comment: Or you could expand map() function and check if array returned by find() is empty

Comment: This brings the following error,                                                                           
 Module parse failed: Unexpected token (154:13)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
|           return schemes.find(function (pv) {
|             return pv.id === id;
>           })?.Name;
|         }).reduce(function (acc, cur) {
|           return "".concat(acc, ", ").concat(cur);

Comment: What I need is when there is not a match to give an empty value to the Name